# Adding Conda Environment in VSCode Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have Conda environment installed, have used it before in PyCharm and Jupyter notebooks, but can't seem to connect the VSCode terminal to conda environment.

When I type a conda command it gives me an error code

> conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - conda
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

I've already selected Conda interpreter in my workspace. How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two installation paths to **Environment Variables--PATH**:

```
\...\Anaconda
\...\Anaconda\Scripts
```

Then type `conda` in Command Promt or Powershell. Getting a list of command usage means you've added it successfully:
[image]

Then **reopen** VS Code. there would no such errors.